# create a new array from the keys of an Array's Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a array of objects, and by using the foreach or map I want to create new array from its keys:

```
[{
    "name": "Dentist Specialist",
    "category": "Roles",
    "path": "cde"
},
{
    "name": "Root Canal Therapy",
    "category": "Procedures",
    "path": "abc"
},
{
    "name": "Live Course",
    "category": "Course Type",
    "path": "mfg"
}]
```

From the above array I need a new ARRAY which will look like this:

```
[{
    "Roles": "Dentist Specialist"
},
{
    "Procedures": "Root Canal Therapy"
},
{
    "Course Type": "Live Course"
}]
```

Just replace the 2nd key with the first key and remove the rest.

Comment: You're making an array of new objects with keys made from the values of one property and values from another. The title sounds like you just want `Object.keys(arr)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) here to achieve the desired result.

```
arr.map(({ category, name }) => ({ [category]: name }));
```

or

```
arr.map((o) => ({ [o.category]: o.name }));
```

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name: "Dentist Specialist",
    category: "Roles",
    path: "cde",
  },
  {
    name: "Root Canal Therapy",
    category: "Procedures",
    path: "abc",
  },
  {
    name: "Live Course",
    category: "Course Type",
    path: "mfg",
  },
];

const result = arr.map((o) => ({ [o.category]: o.name }));
console.log(result);
```